# how to divide the flow of events in the two emitted simultaneously and process them?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

There is a stream of random numbers.

```
rx.Observable
.range (0, 1000)
.map (() -> 200d * Math.random ())
```

I need to be that the flow was divided into two. Numbers less than 100 and the number more than 100.

After that, for numbers less than 100 (chain1):
I need to perform a `request1` to the network, wait for an answer and continue the process chain1 of other operators.

For numbers more than 100 (chain2): 
I have to send another `request2`, wait for an answer and continue the process chain operators on.

`request1` and `request2` don't wait for each other, chains are performed in parallel. But within the chain processing must wait for a response to request.

How do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
rx.Observable
                        .create(subscriber -> {
                            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                                subscriber.onNext(i);
                                Log.i("Iniop", "Create thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                            }
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        })
                        .onBackpressureBuffer()
                        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                        .map(v -> {
                            Log.i("Iniop", "Map thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                            return 200d * Math.random();
                        })
                        .groupBy(k -> {
                                    Log.i("Iniop", "Group thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                                    return k > 100 ? "yes" : "no";
                                }
                                , v -> v)
                        .forEach(gO -> gO.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                                        .map(v -> new Pair<String, Double>(gO.getKey(), v))
                                        .subscribe(v -> {
                                                    Log.i("Iniop", "Key: " + v.first);
                                                    Log.i("Iniop", "Value: " + v.second);
                                                    Log.i("Iniop", "Thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                                                }
                                                , e -> Log.e("Iniop", "Err", e))
                                , e -> Log.e("Iniop", "Err", e));
```

Comment: You may want to move your `subscribeOn` to before you `map` and `groupBy` operators to get them to run on the computation scheduler.